# Vidgear write Video not open

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

[Source code](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear)

Command: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YGKIhftAidQVvR_nMWY3oIhcWFzLERE/view?usp=sharing)

No errors occurred. I have been trying to figure out how to write videos with Vidgear. I am working with windows and webcam.

Error: "Output.mp4"  Opened is a black color. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/11x-q_w59gdaAECtRIqi0MNGIOZ-Vuati/view?usp=sharing)

```
# import required libraries
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
from vidgear.gears import WriteGear
import cv2

# Open live video stream on webcam at first index(i.e. 0) device
stream = CamGear(source=0).start()

# retrieve framerate from CamGear Stream and pass it as `-input_framerate` parameter
output_params = {"-input_framerate":stream.framerate}

# Define writer with defined parameters and suitable output filename for e.g. `Output.mp4`
writer = WriteGear(output_filename = 'Output.mp4', **output_params)

# loop over
while True:

    # read frames from stream
    frame = stream.read()

    # check for frame if None-type
    if frame is None:
        break


    # {do something with the frame here}


    # write frame to writer
    writer.write(frame)

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    # check for 'q' key if pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()

# safely close writer
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [VidGear](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/) library. The [WriteGear](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/gears/writegear/introduction/) API is working just fine. It is your camera that is the real culprit for this problem.

**See this error in your screenshot:**
[image]

This error is due to incorrect backend on your Windows machine. **Try this code instead to fix this error:**

```
# import required libraries
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
from vidgear.gears import WriteGear
import cv2

# Open live video stream on webcam at first index(i.e. 0) device
stream = CamGear(source=0, backend=cv2.CAP_DSHOW).start()

# retrieve framerate from CamGear Stream and pass it as `-input_framerate` parameter
output_params = {"-input_framerate":stream.framerate}

# Define writer with defined parameters and suitable output filename for e.g. `Output.mp4`
writer = WriteGear(output_filename = 'Output.mp4', **output_params)

# loop over
while True:

    # read frames from stream
    frame = stream.read()

    # check for frame if None-type
    if frame is None:
        break


    # {do something with the frame here}


    # write frame to writer
    writer.write(frame)

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    # check for 'q' key if pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()

# safely close writer
writer.close()
```